# Error after transfer from local host to online hosting (HTML PHP)

Tags: php, html, hosting

Recently, i transfer from localhost with xampp to online host using cloud hosting. But then I encounter some error related to the direction of a file. For example, when using in localhost, the URL for directing from the homepage to login: localhost/login. But when I using in the cloud hosting it then become domain.name.com/homepage/login.
This lead to the 404 error. The html code for the file is the same when using in localhost and cloud hosting.

```
<a href="login.html" class="navbar-item ">Login</a>
```

Comment: What is the URL of the current page being viewed when seeing this link?  What is the expected URL for `login.html`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the current URL is foodsafetyeeit2015.info/homepage/login. The expected URL for `login.html` is foodsafetyeeit2015.info/login

Comment: @hainam: Then it sounds like you're using different folder structures on your local workstation than on the deployed website.  Relative paths depend on those structures, so changing them when deploying will break those paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to give the path from the current file location.
Like you can access the files in the same folder using `file.php`
You can access the files in another folder using `folder_name/file.php`
You can access the files in parent folder using  `../file.php`
Thank you

Comment: You can replace file.php with your own file like login.html

Comment: the file I try to access is in the same folder. But when I try to access through the web browser the file direction is moved to a nonexistent folder name @Dinesh

Comment: Can you provide us the code, so we can verify where the mistake is @hainam

Comment: i place the homepage.html and login.html in the same folder.
The code to direct from homepage.html to login.html
`<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                        <a href="login.html" class="dropdown-item">
                                            Login
                                        </a>
                             </div>
                          </div>`

Comment: Did you use any js to change URL pattern?

Comment: oh i found out the solution. This error is caused by the syntax for href to the link.
Must change the code to`href="/login.html" `. Thank you for your help @Denesh

Comment: ok, fine but better you give ./login.html as ./ refers to the current directory